# Retrieve Images from Image Library in thumbnail format using Rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, picture-library, image-rendition

I am trying to retrieve Images from Image Library using Rest API from a mobile device (hence, no cross site calls)..

I am using this approach (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893729/how-to-retrieve-image-files-from-sharepoint-image-library-list-through-rest-ap ) to get file binaries directly, not the server relative URL to avoid cross site requests.

I am able to get the images, however since I want to create a picture gallery on my phone, I want to download thumbnails first and then full image once you click on thumbnail.

Is there any way to get thumbnails using Rest API?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems SharePoint generates thumbnail file name using the following format:

```
thumbnailUrl = <filename>_<fileextension>.jpg
```

Based on that, the following REST endpoint shows to get thumbnail file content:

```
/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{thumbnailUrl}')/$value
```

**Example**

```
var webUrl = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com";
var fileUrl = "/PublishingImages/sample.png";

var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

var requestUrl = String.Format("{0}/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{1}')/$value",webUrl,GetThumbnailUrl(fileUrl));
var response = client.GetAsync(requestUrl, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result;
var fileContent = response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
```

where

```
public static string GetThumbnailUrl(string fileUrl)
{
    return System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUrl) + "_" + System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUrl) +".jpg";
}
```

**Update**

Probably the better option would be to get image thumbnail url via `EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl` property:

- Get image  thumbnail url using request: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<image library title>')/items(<item id>)?$select=EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl`
- then request thumbnail file content: `/_api/web/getfilebyserverrelativeurl('{thumbnailUrl}')/$value`

Comment: For getting file names you could utilize the following request: `/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Images')/items?$select=FileRef`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Vadim, your answer lead me to the right track. Thanks again

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUrl) +".jpg" your are adding extension two times ?

Comment: No, it is System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileUrl)

Comment: sorry. i got it wrong

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint generates thumbnail file name using the following format:

```
thumbnailUrl = <fileFolder>/_t/<filename>_<fileExtension>.jpg
```

So for the file MainLibrary/Tables/Table01.pptx it will be MainLibrary/Tables/_t/Table01_pptx.jpg

In my case I have url:

```
https://companyName.sharepoint.com/sites/projectName
```

So I can get file by this link:

```
https://companyName.sharepoint.com/sites/projectName/_api/web/GetFileByUrl('MainLibrary/Tables/_t/Table01_pptx.jpg')/$value
```