# Picture library thumbnail url

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, pnp-powershell, office

Is there any way in powershellscript to get the thumbnail url from Picture library.? Actually i wan to use in custom search display template to get the thumbnail image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible, but *it is* exposed in the Search Schema in the site settings menu, which is probably better for your purposes anyway.

go to this URL in your site collection:  */_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=sitecol*

and then search for the term 'Thumbnail' without quotes.  You will see the field name which is *PictureThumbnailURL*.  It is mapped (by default) to the following 3 crawled properties:  *ows_AlternateThumbnailUrl, ows_EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl, ows_DMSCoverImage.*

None of these fields: *PictureThumbnailURL, ows_AlternateThumbnailUrl, ows_EncodedAbsThumbnailUrl, ows_DMSCoverImage* are accessible (from my testing) in PnP Sharepoint or SPO cmdlets.

You can also get it via REST.  see this:  [Retrieve Images from Image Library in thumbnail format using Rest API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160274/retrieve-images-from-image-library-in-thumbnail-format-using-rest-api?rq=1)

You can also manually build the URL in the following manner.

**Original Image File Name and URL:**

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/SharedImages/logo-lg.png

**The above Image's Thumbnail URL:**

https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/SharedImages/_t/logo-lg_png.jpg

- the '.' in the File name is converted to an underscore.
- the file extension for the thumbnail is always jpg
- the thumbnail always has the same absolute path as the original file, except it is in a hidden folder within that path '/_t/'

**`Please Mark As Answer If It Answered Your Question`**